# What accounts for the “side effect” of appending items to a Python list by the insert() method?

Tags: python, list, insert, append

I've seen the assertions: " It is not possible to insert at the end of the list with insert(), as that’s what the append method does”.
Here is a piece of Python code that shows some very peculiar behavior.

```
    nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    nums.insert(4, "end")   # index 4 doesn't exist
    nums

    Out: [1, 2, 3, 4, 'end']
```

But in this case list index 4 out of range.
We get the same result with the following code:

```
    nums.insert(len(nums), 'end')
```

I thought this might be just a language or compiler anomaly.
What is going on?

Comment: Where have you seen such assertions?! The premise of the question is just wrong. Everything working as intended.

Comment: The `__doc__` for `insert` reads: "Insert object before index.".  Which is just what it is doing.

Comment: Paul Barry - Head First Python A Brain-Friendly Guide, 2nd Edition (Head First) - 2016 p.65

Answer (score 0):

`list.insert(i, x)` inserts an element **before** the index `i`.

Now, you're right: index 4 doesn't exist in the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` - but anything that's more than 3 just gets appended.

See this example:

```py
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x.insert(4, 5)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

`insert` will never raise an `IndexError` - it just appends if the index is too high